# How to set a ListView Scroll position to bottom, before ListView will appears in Xamarin Forms iOS?

Tags: ios, forms, listview, xamarin, scroll-position

In Xamarin Forms for iOS, I try to set Scroll-position for ListView before it will appears.
When the ListView shown, triggered the visibly scrolling to bottom.
Is there any ideas, how to set the scroll position before the ListView will appear?

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyListView), typeof(NativeiOSListViewRenderer))]
namespace MyApp.iOS.Renderers
{ 
    public class NativeiOSListViewRenderer : ListViewRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<ListView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e); 

            if (e.NewElement != null)
            { 
                var element = e.NewElement as MyListView;

                if (element.ItemsSource is IList items && items.Count > 0)
                { 
                    var tableView = Control as UITableView;
                    var indexPath = NSIndexPath.FromItemSection(itemIndexitems.Count - 1, 0);
                    tableView.ScrollToRow(indexPath, UITableViewScrollPosition.Bottom, false);
                } 
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Check my update answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Cause:**

When you call the code which scroll the listview to buttom in method `OnElementChanged`.The listview have not finished init. So it didn't work.

**Solution:**

You can use `MessagingCenter` to send notification to scroll the listview in the method `OnAppearing`.

> in your contentPage

```
 protected override void OnAppearing()
 {
   base.OnAppearing();
   MessagingCenter.Send<Object>(this, "ScrollToButtom");
 }
```

> in iOS Renderer

```
public class NativeiOSListViewRenderer : ListViewRenderer
{
    public NativeiOSListViewRenderer ()
    {
        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Object>(this, "ScrollToButtom", (obj) => {
            var element = Element as MyListView;
            if (element.ItemsSource is IList<string> items && items.Count > 0)
            {
                var tableView = Control as UITableView;
                var indexPath = NSIndexPath.FromItemSection(items.Count - 1, 0);
                tableView.ScrollToRow(indexPath, UITableViewScrollPosition.Bottom, false);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

**Update:**
The solution works fine on my device.If it still didn't work on your project.You can override the method `WillDisplay`

```
public class MyListViewRenderer:ListViewRenderer,IUITableViewDelegate
{

    bool isFirstLoad = true;

    public MyListViewRenderer()
    {


    }

    [Export("tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:")]
    public void WillDisplay(UITableView tableView,UITableViewCell cell,NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
       if(isFirstLoad)
        {

            var element = Element as MyListView;

            if (element.ItemsSource is IList<string> items && items.Count > 0)
            {

             if(indexPath.Row!=items.Count-1)
                {
                    NSIndexPath nSIndexPath = NSIndexPath.FromItemSection(indexPath.Row + 1, 0);
                    tableView.ScrollToRow(nSIndexPath, UITableViewScrollPosition.Bottom, false);

                }
             else
                {
                    isFirstLoad = false;
                }
            }

        }
    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<ListView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if(Control!=null)
        {
            Control.WeakDelegate = this;
        }

    }

}
```

I have uploaded my sample [here](https://github.com/luczha/sample) ,you can download and have a try.

Comment: In my case scroll works. The main problem this is noticeable scroll. 
OnAppearing not fit, because it makes scrolling noticeable for a user.
I need open the page and the listview already has to be scrolled in bottom position, like at WhatApp. I tried to use SetContentOffset(offset, false), but result the same: until the page appears once, scrolling will be noticeable.

Comment: Did you try my solution? The list view has scrolled before it appears

Comment: OK I will check it again

Comment: Where did you call the method  SetContentOffset(offset, false)?

Comment: The SetContentOffset (offset, false) method was processed when the OnAppearing event raise.

Comment: The solution with "WillDisplay"and IUITableViewDelegate at ListViewRenderer works perfectly. Other solutions did not bring me the desired result. 
Thank you very much for your help! 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1GZ4RTFZe-HtVE5NbEISzqBK10Sc6y2uv

Answer (score 0):

While it is a hack, you may hide the table and then unhide it when it is scrolls (or play with transparency, that must work).

Comment: Thank you. But the best solution for me was override the method WillDisplay